# 301 redirect subfolder while maintaining trailing URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect a section of my website which has a new subfolder name
currently my website looks like the following...

www.website.com/old-folder/product-one
www.website.com/old-folder/product-two

But I need to change the subfolder name, the rest of the URL which contains a number of products is remaining the same see below.

www.website.com/new-folder/product-one
www.website.com/new-folder/product-two

I tried the below which redirects all the URLS included in /old-folder to /new-folder correctly but it sends hem all to the root of /new-folder rather than their unique path.

```
RewriteRule ^old-folder/(.*)$ /new-folder/(.*)? [L,R=301]
```

Any Help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `$1` to backreference what you've matched:

```
RewriteRule ^old-folder/(.*)$ /new-folder/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You can also use mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/old-folder/(.*)$ /new-folder/$1
```